# Instead of Value(Long) Null is passing in JSP, So proper values are not displaying in JSP pages

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, jpa

**I have Reservation Entity as:**

```
package com.nischal.flightreservation.entities;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "RESERVATION")
public class Reservation extends AbstractEntity{
@Column(name = "checked_in")
private Boolean checkedIn;
@Column(name = "no_of_bags")
private int noOfBags;
@OneToOne
private Passenger passenger;
@OneToOne
private Flight flight;

public Boolean getCheckedIn() {
    return checkedIn;
}

public void setCheckedIn(Boolean checkedIn) {
    this.checkedIn = checkedIn;
}

public int getNoOfBags() {
    return noOfBags;
}

public void setNoOfBags(int noOfBags) {
    this.noOfBags = noOfBags;
}

public Passenger getPassenger() {
    return passenger;
}

public void setPassenger(Passenger passenger) {
    this.passenger = passenger;
}

public Flight getFlight() {
    return flight;
}

public void setFlight(Flight flight) {
    this.flight = flight;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Reservation [checkedIn=" + checkedIn + ", noOfBags=" + noOfBags + ", passenger="
            + passenger + ", flight=" + flight + "]";
}
```

}

**I have Abstract Entity class as:**

```
package com.nischal.flightreservation.entities;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

**I have FlightController as:**

```
package com.nischal.flightreservation.controllers;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import com.nischal.flightreservation.entities.Flight;
import com.nischal.flightreservation.repos.FlightRepository;

@Controller
public class FlightController {

@Autowired
private FlightRepository flightRepository;

@RequestMapping("/findFlights")
public String findFlights(@RequestParam(name = "from") String from, @RequestParam(name = "to") String to,@RequestParam(name = "departureDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") Date departureDate ,ModelMap modelMap) {
    List<Flight> flights = flightRepository.findFlights(from, to, departureDate);
    modelMap.addAttribute("flights",flights);

    return "displayFlights";

}
```

}

**I have "displayFlights.jsp" which is responsible to displaying All the available Flights and which is working Fine.**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Airlines</th>
        <th>Departure City</th>
        <th>Arrival City</th>
        <th>Departure Time</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items = "${flights}" var = "flight">
    <tr>
        <td>${ flight.operatingAirlines}</td>
        <td>${ flight.departureCity}</td>
        <td>${ flight.arrivalCity}</td>
        <td>${ flight.estimatedDepartureTime}</td>
        <td><a href = "showCompleteReservation?flightId=${flight.id }">Select</a>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>

</table>
```

**I have ReservationController as:**

```
package com.nischal.flightreservation.controllers;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import com.nischal.flightreservation.dto.ReservationRequest;
import com.nischal.flightreservation.entities.Flight;
import com.nischal.flightreservation.entities.Reservation;
import com.nischal.flightreservation.repos.FlightRepository;
import com.nischal.flightreservation.services.ReservationService;

@Controller
public class ReservationController {

@Autowired
FlightRepository flightRepository;

@Autowired
ReservationService reservationService;



@RequestMapping("/showCompleteReservation")
public String showCompleteReservation(@RequestParam("flightId") int flightId,ModelMap 
modelMap) {
    Flight flight = flightRepository.findById((long) flightId).orElse(null);
    modelMap.addAttribute("flight",flight);
    return "completeReservation";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/completeReservation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String completeReservation(ReservationRequest request, 
        @Valid Reservation reservation, BindingResult bindingResult,ModelMap modelMap) {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "completeReservation";
    }
    else {
    modelMap.addAttribute("msg", "Reservation Saved Successfully. "+reservation.getId());
    return "reservationConfirmation";
    }
}
```

}

**and completeReservation.jsp is as:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Reservation Info</title>
</head>
<body>

Airline: ${flight.operatingAirlines }<br>
Departure City: ${flight.operatingAirlines }<br>
Arrival City: ${flight.arrivalCity }<br>

<form action = "completeReservation" method = "post">
    <pre>
        <h2>Passenger Details</h2>
        First Name: <input type = "text" name = "passengerFirstName"/>
        Middle Name: <input type = "text" name = "passengerMiddleName"/>
        Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "passengerLastName"/>
        Email: <input type = "email" name = "passengerEmail"/>
        Phone: <input type = "text" name = "passengerPhone"/>

        <h2>Card Details</h2>
        Name on the Card: <input type = "text" name = "nameOnTheCard"/>
        Card Number: <input type = "text" name = "cardNumber"/>
        Expiration Date: <input type = "text" name = "expirationDate"/>
        Three Digit Sec Code: <input type = "text" name = "threeDigitSecCode"/>
        <input type = "hidden" name = "flightId" value = "${flight.id }"/>
        <input type = "Submit" value = "Confirm"/>


    </pre>

</form>
```

**But Instead of Displaying the name of Operating Airlines, Departure City, Arrival City Nothing is Displayed. I have had attached the photo here as:**

[image]

**and whenever i click on the confirm button. The reservation msg is displayed as:**
[image]

**I want Reservation id there instead of Null.**

Comment: In your ReservationController you can directly use the flightId of type long instead of using int and cast it to long. In your Abstractclass the Id is also of type long so changing it to long makes sense. And did you check that your flightRepository gets a value? If not check it there or post code.

Comment: yes, flightRepository gets a value. I have already posted the code of flightRepository. Please help me to sort this error out

Comment: Have you tried to remove the ".orElse(null)" Doesn't seem to be needed cause your "findById" function must return all possible values.

Comment: If i remove .orElse(null) then the return type becomes <Option>. and I don't know how to use it. I don't know how to deal with it. But I don't think it is causing error